# How to hide seek bar in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am doing a video player using JavaScript with basic playback features and have listeners for Ad starts and Ad ended. I hide seekbar when Ad is playing and make visible after Ad end. Now my problem is if I call a play function or pause method from console when Ad is playing the seekbar get visible instead of hide.

```
// Ad start event
this.onAdStartedEvent = function(data) {
  isAdPlaying = true;
  // code for hide seekbar
  OO.$(".oo-control-bar").hide();
}
// Ad end event
this.onAdCompletedEvent = function(data) {
  isAdPlaying = false;
  OO.$(".oo-control-bar").show();
}
// pause method
this.pause = function(data){
 if(isAdPlaying){
   OO.$(".oo-control-bar").hide(); // It does not hide the seekbar
  }
}
```

I call the `pause()` method from console the seek bar code get executed but its not hidden. 
Please let me know how to get hide the `seekbar` from `pause` method

Comment: `OO.$(".oo-control-bar")` ?  What is `OO` ?

Comment: does `isAdPlaying` global? If not, your problem is here

Comment: @Fefux, isAdPlaying is global variable

Comment: Did you try to log value of `isAdPlaying` and `OO` when you call pause method?

Comment: OO its a third party library.

Comment: Yes, if I log get true in the console

Comment: And what is the return of `$(".oo-control-bar")` and `$(".oo-control-bar").hide()`?

Comment: its return following Object { 0: <div.oo-control-bar.oo-control-bar-hidden>, length: 1, prevObject: Object, context: HTMLDocument → index.html, selector: ".oo-control-bar" }